# " Not a git repository:" error message on running Contiki tutorial

Tags: linux, git, contiki

I'm trying to run the hello-world example in contiki on a sky tmote. I'm using ubuntu and followed this tutorial: http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html

```
make TARGET=z1 hello-world
make TARGET=z1 savetarget
make hello-world.upload
```

*make -k -j 20 z1-reset-sequence
using saved target 'z1'
fatal: Not a git repository: '../../.git'

```
make login
```

*../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux: 1: ../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** [login] Fehler 2

- errors, I could not solve these errors.
  PS: I am a beginer to ubuntu and Contiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is clear: "Not a git repository:" means that you tried to use git in a directory with no git repository. If you meant to initiate a git repo to backup your code, then:

```
cd path/to/your/project
git init
git add --all
git commit -m'a message explaining what's done already'
```

Also, read manuals: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2